# WPF: ControlTemplate vs Style that Changes Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Inside App.xaml I may have:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="roundButton">
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate Target="{x:Type Button}">
            bla bla bla...
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

vs. just going

```
<ControlTemplate Target="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="roundButton">
    bla bla bla...
</ControlTemplate>
```

I'm confused, which should I use / what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Style you could also change other values of the button at the same time.
Using the ControlTemplate you can only change the template.
So which is appropriate?